# Why is it not possible to connect to my container from outside

Tags: docker, curl

I'm trying to execute a small Scala server in my computer, the code work well so the problem in my opinion is in the docker side.

Here you can see my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./target/scala-2.13/hello-world-assembly-1.0.jar /usr/app/

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr/app

CMD ["java", "-jar", "hello-world-assembly-1.0.jar"]
```

Building command: `docker build -t carloshn90/first-scala-server:latest .`

Executing command: `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name scala-server -it carloshn90/first-scala-server:latest`

The problem is that when I try to execute a curl inside the container is working well:
`docker exec scala-server curl localhost:8080` but not from outside.

Docker container status:

[image: docker ps status]

Curl inside the container:

[image: curl inside container]

Finally here the same curl but from outside the container:

[image: curl outside container]

My docker version is 19.03.08 and the operative system is macOS Catalina.

I would appreciate if someone have any idea about how to solve this problem

-------- Solution --------

Maybe this information is useful for others, in my case the issue was that the local address was localhost instead 0.0.0.0:

```
/usr/app # netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:http-alt      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     172119
```

When the correct local address should be 0.0.0.0

```
/usr/app # netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http-alt        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     215241
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output into your question as text rather than images. Images are hard to read and we can't copy, edit, or search them.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your app inside the container is listening on the external ip, and not only localhost (127.0.0.1). This is typical done by listening on *:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Run this from outside the container:

```
curl -L http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: This command return curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8080

Comment: Please try the updated command. Also, can you check the status of the firewall? Is it active?

Comment: Same result, I executed the docker image in Windows and I found the same error, so I think there is some issue with my image. This evening I would try to create another image with a spring boot server and debug it